# Get dbIds from 3D object tree using Model Derivative API

Tags: autodesk-model-derivative

Is there an example of reading the object tree and associated dbIds (typically found in the Autodesk viewer) from the Model Derivative API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First call that endpoint to get the guid of the view:

[https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-GET](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-GET/)

Then call that second endpoint passing in the guid obtained in the first call:

[https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-GET](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-GET/)

Take a look at the links for example payload of the responses. Using the Forge SDKs those endpoints are called respectively `getMetadata` and `getModelviewMetadata`.

Comment: Thank you Philippe, that is what we needed.  I'm adding the below link as documentation for future readers. 
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/get-all-dbid-without-enumerating-model-hierarchy